# What is the equivalent "grep" command in php?

Tags: php, bash, awk

Please bear with me since I'm still really new in PHP. So I have a `config` file like this:

```
profile 'axisssh2'
server '110.251.223.161'
source_update 'http://myweb.com:81/profile'
file_config 'udp.group-1194-exp11nov.ovpn'
use_config 'yes'
ssh_account 'sgdo.ssh'
```

I want to create a PHP variable named `$currentprofile` with the value of `axisssh2`, **the value keeps changing**. With `grep` in bash I can just do

```
currentprofile=$(cat config | grep ^profile | awk -F "'" '{print $2}')
```

But I have no idea how to do that with PHP. Please kindy help me how to do that, thank you.

UPDATE:
So I tried `preg_match` like this but it only shows the value of `1`

```
$config=file_get_contents('/root/config');
$currentprofile=preg_match('/^profile /', $config);
echo "Current Profile: ".$currentprofile;
```

Please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: You could use `preg_match`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php https://eval.in/663244

Comment: To finish @chris85 his answer: preg_match('/^profile/', $currentprofile)

Comment: You could use `fgetcsv()` with space as the separator.  Probably how I would do it.

Comment: Or replace space with `=` and use `parse_ini_file()/string()`.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and I updated my questions guys, please take a look once more.

Comment: Did you look at the docs to see what `preg_match()` returns and what arguments are passed?  Anyway, `parse_ini_string()` probably the easiest and you can get all the vars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb to answer a question that you didn't ask.  You'd be better off using [parse_ini_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php) or [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).  The `.ini` file would need the following format `profile='axisssh2'`, so replace the space:

```
$array = parse_ini_string(str_replace(' ', '=', file_get_contents($file)));
print_r($array);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [profile] => axisssh2
    [server] => 110.251.223.161
    [source_update] => http://myweb.com:81/profile
    [file_config] => udp.group-1194-exp11nov.ovpn
    [use_config] => yes
    [ssh_account] => sgdo.ssh
)
```

So just:

```
echo $array['profile'];
```

But the answer to your question would be:

- [preg_grep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)
- [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

`preg_match` returns the number of matches (which is why you get 1) but you can get the actual matches with a capture group which will populate the third argument:

```
$config = file_get_contents('/root/config');
$currentprofile = preg_match("/^profile '(.*)'/", $config, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but why do you have to replace a space with a `=` ?

Comment: That's what `parse_ini_string()` expects.  Or loop through and use `fgetcsv()`

Comment: Thank you for answering, can you please answer it with `preg_match` as well ? so that I can also learn how to do it with `preg_match` instead of `parse_ini_string`. I'm really sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: See also the documentation on how to use .ini-files with sections (yields a nested array with configuration values): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php